# ValueError in DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My objective is to..

- if the dataframe is empty, i need to insert a row with `index->value of the variable URL` and `columns-> value of URL along with the sorted_list`
- if non-empty, i need to insert a row with `index->value of the variable URL` and `columns->sorted_list`

What I did was... I initialized a DataFrame `self.pd` and then for each row with values as above said I created a local DataFrame variable `df1` and append it to `self.df`.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

class Reward_Matrix:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()

    def add(self, URL, webpage_list):
        sorted_list = []
        check_list = list(self.df.columns.values)
        print('check_list: ',check_list)
        for i in webpage_list:     #to ensure no duplication columns
            if i not in check_list:
                sorted_list.append(i)
        if self.df.empty:
            sorted_list.insert(0, URL)
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(0,index=[URL], columns=[sorted_list])
        else:
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(0,index=[URL], columns=[sorted_list])
        print(df1)
        print('sorted_list: ',sorted_list)
        print("length: ",len(df1.columns))
        self.df.append(df1)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4294, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))]
  File "...Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2719, in make_block
return klass(values, ndim=ndim, fastpath=fastpath, placement=placement)
  File "...Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 115, in __init__
len(self.mgr_locs)))
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 450

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...eclipse-workspace\Crawler\crawl_core\src_main\run.py", line 23, in test_start
test.crawl_run(self.URL)
  File "...eclipse-workspace\Crawler\crawl_core\src_main\test_crawl.py", line 42, in crawl_run
self.reward.add(URL, webpage_list)
  File "...eclipse-workspace\Crawler\crawl_core\src_main\dynamic_matrix.py", line 21, in add
df1 = pd.DataFrame(0,index=[URL], columns=[sorted_list])
  File "...Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 352, in __init__
copy=False)
  File "...Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 483, in _init_ndarray
return create_block_manager_from_blocks([values], [columns, index])
  File "...Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4303, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
  File "...Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4280, in construction_error
passed, implied))
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (450, 1)
```

I am not well-versed with DataFrame and Pandas. I had been getting this error for quite some time and I am getting confused when I go through similar questions asked in StackOverflow as I can't understand where I went wrong!

Can someone help me out?

Comment: @jezrael ee! I think that's correct. A dataframe `df1` with index `URL` and columns as specified... Shouldn't index and columns must be specified as a collection? and the `0` -> I wanted all the values of `df1` to be 0. Is there something wrong? like syntax?

Comment: I add sample, give me a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need remove `[]`, because else get nested list:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(0,index=[URL], columns=sorted_list)
```

Sample:

```
sorted_list = ['a','b','c']
URL = 'url1'
df1 = pd.DataFrame(0,index=[URL], columns=sorted_list)
print (df1)
      a  b  c
url1  0  0  0

df1 = pd.DataFrame(0,index=[URL], columns=[sorted_list])
print (df1)

>ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (3, 1)
```

Comment: Yes! U were right! That did remove the error. But now when I printed the DataFrame after `self.df.append(df1)` I get an empty one!
    `Empty DataFrame
    Columns: []
    Index: []`. Won't appending work here?

Comment: So there has to be another problem, give me some time.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but `return self.df.append(df1)` should work

Comment: And last problem `if i not in check_list:` I think you need `if i in check_list:`

Comment: for `return self.df.append(df1)` - > yes that is working but why is that `print(self.df.append(df1))`? Because I needed to use `self.df.append(df1)` in some other function in the same class again. But it is empty!

Comment: because use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), not `python append`

Comment: for `if i not in check_list:` -> I think this is right.. I want all values in webpage_list but not in check_list to be stored in stored_list

Comment: If I give `print(self.df.append(df1))` I get the desired dataframe. But when i append it first (`self.df.append(df1)`) and then print it (`print(self.df)`) i get empty dataframe!

Comment: Maybe need `self.df = self.df.append(df1)` - assign back

Comment: Urghhh! That was it! Thanks and that did the job! jeez i missed it!